# percentage of probability

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

I want to pose a question. I wonder what natural ways to say the following are:

> 1 What is the percent probability that aliens exist?
>
> 2 What is the percentage of probability that aliens exist?
>
> 3 What is the percentage of the probability of the existence of
> aliens?

How can I answer?

> 1a) There is a low/high percent probability that aliens exist.
>
> 2a) There is a low/high percentage of probability that aliens exist.
>
> 3a) There is a low/high percentage of the probability of the existence
> of aliens.

Are any of them grammatically wrong?

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, separate from the English grammar, what exactly do you mean by "percent(age) probability"? "Probability" does not have a meaning that is independent of one person's personal opinion. The factors used in its calculation can and will vary according to the opinions of the calculator. So it makes no sense to ask for THE percentage probability - but perhaps your/his/her probability.

Comment: Is there anything other than someone's opinion at all?

Comment: I cannot think there is a scientific way of claculating the chances of anything happening, only by some form of statistical likelihood. And what statistics one chooses to employ and what error corrections one introduces must be all a matter of opinion. And as we have no statistics involving aliens I am wondering on what one might base any probability that they exist.

Comment: On their hunch.

Comment: All of them would be improved by removing all reference to percent(age) as it is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to represent this is "percent probability", not "percentage of the probability" or "percentage probability", so I would say the first question is the best. If you want to improve it, you can remove "percent". (you can also remove "probability" and add "likelihood" if you want)

Again 1a) is the best answer, but it can be made better by removing "percent".

Comment: I think in Britain we would say "percentage probability".